When running official Python TensorFlow Probability tutorial locally, model fails to complete fit with VI. Setting jit_compile=False fits correctly
I am trying to get TFP and TF running locally with GPU support.  I set up a virtual environment for these packages and their dependencies, as well as upgrading my NVIDIA GPU driver, CUDA Toolkit, cuDNN, etc.  I was working through this tutorial for fitting a structural time series (STS) model using VI.  TF can see my GPU.
When generating the negative ELBO loss curve, the fit seems to work normally for ~30 steps before returning nans for the remaining steps.
System:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 64-bit
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti
NVIDIA Driver Version: 555.42.06
CUDA Version: 12.5
cuDNN 8.9.7.29
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jun__6_02:18:23_PDT_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.5, V12.5.82
Build cuda_12.5.r12.5/compiler.34385749_0
Relevant packages
TF/TFP conda env:
Tensorflow                2.16.2
Tensorflow Probability    0.24.0
nvidia-cublas-cu12        12.3.4.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.3.101
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12     12.3.107
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12    12.3.107
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.3.101
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         8.9.7.29
nvidia-cufft-cu12         11.0.12.1
nvidia-curand-cu12        10.3.4.107
nvidia-cusolver-cu12      11.5.4.101
nvidia-cusparse-cu12      12.2.0.103
nvidia-nccl-cu12          2.19.3
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12     12.3.101
TFP/JAX virtualenv:
Tensorflow Probability    0.25.0-dev20240729 (nightly)
JAX                       0.4.31
nvidia-cublas-cu12        12.5.3.2
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.5.82
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12     12.5.82
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.5.82
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         9.2.1.18
nvidia-cufft-cu12         11.2.3.61
nvidia-cusolver-cu12      11.6.3.83
nvidia-cusparse-cu12      12.5.1.3
nvidia-nccl-cu12          2.22.3
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12     12.5.82
I was able to replicate the tutorial in Colab using the T4 GPU runtime.
Setting jit_compile=False leads to a big slow-down but the fitting completes as expected (reaches a minimum, no nans).  I've tried playing around with lower learning rates (0.001,0.01) and optimizers (RMSprop, Adamax) using jit_compile=True without success.  Setting jit_compile=False with these other optimizers and learning rates again leads to successful completion.
I also tried running through the JAX version of the tutorial in a fresh virtualenv without TF (pip install -Uq tfp-nightly[jax] > /dev/null) and experienced the same problem.  JAX could also see my GPU.
I tried using nvidia-smi to keep an eye on some GPU stats.  In the TF/TFP conda environment, when running with jit_compile=True, GPU utilization peaked around 96%.  TF was allocating 10+Gb from my GPU before fitting.  I tried using tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True) and this limited GPU memory allocation to ~650Mb but with the same peak GPU utilization of 96%, and the same outcome (fitting for ~30 steps followed by nans).
With jit_compile=False, GPU utilization never exceeded 55%.  Again, TF was allocating 10+Gb from my GPU before fitting.  Setting memory growth here also had no effect on GPU utilization but decreased GPU memory allocation to ~450Mb.
At this point I've tried lots of different things to get this working efficiently on my GPU.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.
